# Self Hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am looking into make a self hosted WCF service from within my app. I am trying to follow the example on Microsoft Sites http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.100).aspx but I am having a problem.

When the program runs I can go onto the web page where it says that I can run svcutil.exe to generate the client class or when I go into the WCF test client that the tutorial says I get the error

```
Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
```

From the svcutil.exe I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>svcutil http://localhost:
6525/hello
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost:6525/hello' using WS-Meta
data Exchange or DISCO.
Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata docu
ments did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assembl
ies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to
use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

Below is the code for my WCF app

```
public interface IHelloWorldService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string SayHello(string firstName, string lastName);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6525/hello");

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
            {
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at: {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service");
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();

            }
        }

        public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
        {
            public string SayHello(string firstName, string lastName)
            {
                return string.Format("Hello {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first look it's hard to figure out the issue of your problem but as I've test your code I found out the something is missing from your code. You forgot to expose your contract to the client. Your interface has missing [ServiceContract] attribute. Below will solve your problem hope this helps.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string firstName, string lastName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the exact problem. Working fine now

Comment: @Benjiman I hadn't added the ``[ServiceContract]`` above the public interface IHelloWorldService definition

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same issue. It turned out that after editing `app.config`, the designer stopped auto updating the `app.config` file. Can you post the markup from `app.config`?

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is not exposing here , you need to add new EndPoint for this and need to enable it in the service config. Please do the following.

```
<service name="ConsoleApplication1.WCFService1" behaviorConfiguration="newBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/WCFService1" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
<service>
```

and in the service behaviors

```
<serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="newBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

I have tried this and generated the proxy without any problems. Please let me know any concerns.